# OpenGL ES Panning (X, Y, Z) based on rotation matrix

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I'm implementing panning for an OpenGL ES 2.0 iOS app and am struggling with panning in the z-direction in certain case. Initially when the model loads, y+ is towards the top of the screen, x+ is pointing to the left of the screen and z+ is coming at the user out of the screen. Panning works as expected in this - panning "right" moves the model as expected, along the positive x axis. Y works as well - panning "up" moves the mode along the positive y axis (coordinates come negative so we just flip the coordinate to behave correctly). The problem is always with the z-axis, when the model is rotated so the z+ axis is now pointing to the right, panning "right" I receive negative z values and panning to the left I get positive values so it seems like the coordinates are flipped like the z-axis. The same logic occurs when z+ is pointing to the left of the screen - negative values for panning left and positive for panning right. So far so good.

When the z+ is facing towards the top of the screen now, panning up gives me positive values when all other orientations gave me negative values when panning along z+. Panning down gives me negative values. So when z is left/right I need to flip the coordinates, but when z is up/down if I do that the panning is backwards. All I am doing is retrieving the touch location from the pan gesture, creating a `GLKVector3` with z = 0 then applying my current model view matrix to this vector. The model view matrix should apply the current rotation so the given point and output the point accordingly based on the rotation...or so I thought. Is there some logic I am missing to handle panning in the z direction accurately?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the move in camera space (along camera's left and up vectors), use camera orientation's axes multiplied with x and y panning values.

To transform in object space you can multiply your vector with the inverse matrix of model view matrix. (for accuracy, you can use inverse of model view projection matrix, but you should use z = nearPlane instead of 0)

Comment: Essentially my camera never moves, it's always focused at 0, 0, and at the near plane. I'm assuming that's why you also added the second sentence since that sounds like what I want to accomplish. So take my translation point from eye coordinates, use z = near plane and multiply this by the inverse or model view matrix * projection matrix?

Comment: Yes, that should transform it in your object space.

Comment: This now creates the opposite effect - z+ pointing towards the top screen works correctly since z values are negative panning up and positive panning down. When z+ runs to the right of the screen, z values are + panning right and negative panning left so one set still pans the opposite as expected.

    locationVector = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(GLKMatrix4Multiply(inverseModelViewMatrix, self.projectionMatrix), locationVector);

Comment: well you need locationVector = MultiplyVector(Inverse(Multiply(modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix)), locationVector) (with the exact syntax, I don't know exactly what function names are on your side)

Comment: Tried this as well, same results. Essentially I don't know why z+ has different behaviors determining if it's pointing to the top of the screen as opposed to the right of the screen. I thought my rotation matrix would take care of determining this.